# Unitialized Constant Devise RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, devise

I'm using a Rails 4 App with RSpec and Capybara.

My gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do 
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "guard-rspec"
end
```

My spec_helper.rb file looks like:

```
require "capybara/rspec"
include Capybara::DSL

RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
   config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

But for some reason I'm getting the error: `uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)`
. In my app, Devise is working correctly, though, and I have the ControllerMacros file in spec/support.

Comment: What's the full stack trace?  Where is the error occurring?

Comment: please show your gemfile and also tell which version of ruby/rails you are using?

Comment: The errors are occurring in the spec_helper.rb file

Comment: @SachinSingh, My gemfile is in the question. Do you mean the full gemfile? I'm using rails 4.

Comment: @SachinSingh, Ok just added it.

Comment: @the_ you have not added `devise` gem to your gemfile, add it and do `bundle install`.

Comment: @SachinSingh, Oops I had somehow I missed copying that to the question but I really do have in my Gemfile. I just edited the question

Comment: @the_ add these two line to spec_helper.rb at very top of file and try.
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55544/discussion-between-sachin-singh-and-the).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this out:

your spec_helper should be like

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment",__FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require "capybara/rspec"
include Capybara::DSL

RSpec.configure do |config|
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: Add the config lines to `spec/rails_helper.rb` instead of `spec/spec_helper.rb` if you're using the rspec-rails gem